# Consumer Thread and SQS - Preventing from submitting null data to the blocking queue and finding a better way to call the consumer threads at runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-sqs, producer-consumer

I have a standard SQS and I need to read data from it using multiple consumer threads. 
To achieve the same, I have written the following method ( in Java):

```
 public void consume() {
      ExecutorService exService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
      
      while(true) {
          exService.execute(()->{
              try {
              /* the following code submits a null data to the blocking queue when the queue(sqs) is empty*/
              OrderQ order = queueMessagingTemplate.receiveAndConvert(StringConstants.QUEUE_NAME
                      , OrderQ.class);
              if(order!=null)
                  repstiory.saveOrder(order);
              log.debug("Received from queue:"+ order);
              }catch(Exception exc) {
                  log.error("couldn't read msg from queue");
                  throw new CouldNotReadMessageFromSQSException("couldn't read msg from queue");
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

and, as of now, I have two approaches to call the above method and start consuming the messages 
from the queue  stated as follows along with the issues associated with them: 
Approach-1 : 
create a rest api and call this method. This approach won't work in production and also when
 the queue is empty, `null` will keep getting populated in the blocking queue of the thread pool.
 So, this is clearly not a good approach.
 **Question**-How can I ensure that only 'not null' data is submitted to the blocking queue?

Approach-2: 
calling the consume method from `CommandLineRunner` but the issue is, the queue, most probably,
 won't have data as soon as the application starts and will run into the same problem as described in the 1st approach.

**Problem-1**:What can be a better solution to handle the null data problem? 
**problem-2**:what can be better way to call the `consume` method, considering the production environment?

Kindly suggest solutions and best practices to achieve the same.

Comment: Why doesn't your `!= null` check work? Shouldn't the `while (true)` be *inside* the executor? Instead of submitting an endless number of execution tasks to the executor have just three long running executors!? What blocking queue are you referring to?

Comment: `!=null` is preventing from inserting `null` data in the DB. `while(true)` inside the executor will make it a single threaded consumer and there would not benefit of using a thread pool. `BlockingQueue`  is used by the thread pool to make worker threads blocked/wait until the data /space is available

Comment: !=null is preventing from inserting null data in the DB - then what is the actual problem? I do not see how multithreading is helping you at all here - just having a single thread would probably make everything easier. Submitting an infinite number of tasks all just querying SQS only once is certainly worse performance than having one or three tasks listening to the queue continously.

Comment: @luk2302   I want to listen to the queue through multiple threads and to achieve that I am submitting `reading from queue` tasks to the executor. How can I improve this? I am looking for something like, as you mentioend, - `..having one or three tasks listening to the queue continously`

Comment: @luk2302 basically, you are saying that,  I should call `exService.execute( ()-> {} ) ` 2 or 3 times and keeping the while loop inside them?